# How do I add rows to a table in React Hooks without getting duplicates?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm attempting to create a data table with react hooks but I keep getting duplicates rows in my state. Here is the call where I'm getting values doing some manipulation and then calling my function to update state:

```
var tableRowIndex = 0;
const CoinTable = () => {
    const baseURL = 'endpoint/';
    const [tableRows, setRows] = useState([] as any);


    const getCurrentPrice = async (inputs: any) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${inputs.currency}/USD`)
        let currentPrice = response.data
        inputs.cryptoPrice = currentPrice.rate;
        let coinsRequired = inputs.amount / inputs.cryptoPrice;
        inputs.amtCrypto = coinsRequired.toFixed(8);
        addNewRow(inputs)
    }
```

Here is my function where I'm attempting to update state

```
 const addNewRow = (inputs: any) => {
        tableRowIndex++
        inputs.index = tableRowIndex
        setRows([...tableRows, inputs])
    }
```

This is the rest of the components where I'm mapping through my rows and outputting in my JSX.

```
const rows = tableRows.map((row: any) => {
        return (
            <TableRow
                key={tableRowIndex}
                addNewRow={addNewRow}
                removeRow={removeRowHandler}
                getCurrentPrice={getCurrentPrice}
                row={row}
            />
        )
    })
    
    return (
        <>
            <AddItem
                getCurrentPrice={getCurrentPrice}
            />
            {tableRows.length > 0 &&
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Merchant</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Amount(Crypto)</th>
                            <th>Currency</th>
                            <th>Price/crypto(USD)</th>
                            <th>Amount(USD)</th>
                        </tr>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            }
        </>
    )
}

export default CoinTable;
```

Inputs is object containing user inputs to be rendered as a new row. It appears to be an issue as to how I'm updating state using the spread operator but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the data being mapped to rows have GUIDs or any unique field properties you could test/assert uniqueness? Also, using the mapped array index isn't an ideal React key use, you should avoid using the index and instead use a GUID or unique field property. Other than this, what have you tried already in removing duplicates?

Comment: So the mapped data doesn't have a GUID or any ID by default, therefore I'm attempting to add manually. Do you think this duplication has to do w/ the lack of a key. Given I am getting warnings in the console about the key usage being duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are using the single `tableRowIndex` "global" value as the React key for every mapped element. You likely meant to use the `row` index`generated in`addNewRow`when adding an element to the`tableRows` state.

```
const addNewRow = (inputs: any) => {
  tableRowIndex++;
  inputs.index = tableRowIndex; // <-- assigned here
  setRows([...tableRows, inputs]);
}
```

...

```
const rows = tableRows.map((row: any) => {
  return (
    <TableRow
      key={row.index} // <-- used here
      addNewRow={addNewRow}
      removeRow={removeRowHandler}
      getCurrentPrice={getCurrentPrice}
      row={row}
    />
  )
})
```

A more idiomatic method would be to call this augmented property `id` so it's ***abundantly*** clear it's not any array index and actually a unique value assigned to each element. I'd even go as far as to say you might want to use a library that generates GUIDs for you. [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is a great one.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';
```

...

```
const addNewRow = (inputs: any) => {
  setRows(rowData => [
    ...rowData,
    {
      ...inputs,   // <-- don't mutate inputs object
      id: v4uuid() // <-- assign unique id
    },
  ]);
}
```

...

```
const rows = tableRows.map((row: any) => {
  return (
    <TableRow
      key={row.id}
      addNewRow={addNewRow}
      removeRow={removeRowHandler}
      getCurrentPrice={getCurrentPrice}
      row={row}
    />
  )
})
```